# How can I do a case-insensitive search with Rose::DB::Object?

Tags: case-insensitive, string-search, rose-db-object

How can I do a case-insensitive search with `Rose::DB::Object`?

Here is the form of a `Rose::DB::Object` search:

```
my $my_matches = $_my_table_class_mgr->get_objects(
    query => [
        my_field => $my_value,
    ],
);
```

Is there something I can add to the "query" parameters, perhaps?  But, I don't see anything that addresses this in [here](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Rose-DB-Object/lib/Rose/DB/Object/QueryBuilder.pm) (in the `Rose::DB::Object::QueryBuilder` documentation).

What am I missing?  And where is what I am missing documented?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it.  It is quite simple.  You have to do an 'imatch' operation in the query parameter.  The code looks like this:

```
my $my_matches = $_my_table_class_mgr->get_objects(
    query => [
        my_field => {imatch => $my_value},
    ],
);
```

So, very simple solution.

I figured this out by studying the `Rose::DB::Object::QueryBuilder` documentation [here](http://search.cpan.org/~jsiracusa/Rose-DB-Object-0.806/lib/Rose/DB/Object/QueryBuilder.pm#query).  Look under the part where it says 'Comparisons:' and then, just beneath that, where it says '"OP" can be any of the following:'.

Thank you to anyone who might have considered helping with this.  I hope it helps a future newbie to Rose::DB::Object.